# Why does a spark RDD behave differently depending on contents?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Based on [this description of datasets and dataframes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-datasets) I wrote this very short test code which works.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val thing = Seq("Spark I am your father", "May the spark be with you", "Spark I am your father")
val wordsDataset = sc.parallelize(thing).toDS()
```

If that works... why does running this give me a

> error: value toDS is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Table]

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val sequence = spark.catalog.listDatabases().collect().flatMap(db =>
  spark.catalog.listTables(db.name).collect()).toSeq
val result = sc.parallelize(sequence).toDS()
```

Comment: My guess is One returns an `RDD[String]` the other `RDD[Table]` and Spark doesn't know how to serialize `Table` in this context

Comment: But how could `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Table]` have different members to `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toDS()` is **not** a member of `RRD[T]`. Welcome to the bizarre world of Scala implicits where nothing is what it seems to be.

`toDS()` is a member of `DatasetHolder[T]`. In `SparkSession`, there is an object called `implicits`. When brought in scope with an expression like `import sc.implicits._`, an implicit method called `rddToDatasetHolder` becomes available for resolution:

```scala
implicit def rddToDatasetHolder[T](rdd: RDD[T])(implicit arg0: Encoder[T]): DatasetHolder[T]
```

When you call `rdd.toDS()`, the compiler first searches the `RDD` class and all of its superclasses for a method called `toDS()`. It doesn't find one so what it does is start searching all the compatible implicits in scope. While doing so, it finds the `rddToDatasetHolder` method which accepts an `RDD` instance and returns an object of a type which does have a `toDS()` method. Basically, the compiler rewrites:

```scala
sc.parallelize(sequence).toDS()
```

into

```scala
SparkSession.implicits.rddToDatasetHolder(sc.parallelize(sequence)).toDS()
```

Now, if you look at `rddToDatasetHolder` itself, it has two argument lists:

```scala
(rdd: RDD[T])
(implicit arg0: Encoder[T])
```

Implicit arguments in Scala are optional and if you do not supply the argument explicitly, the compiler searches the scope for implicits that match the required argument type and passes whatever object it finds or can construct. In this particular case, it looks for an instance of the `Encoder[T]` type. There are many predefined encoders for the standard Scala types, but for most complex custom types no predefined encoders exist.

So, in short: The existence of a predefined `Encoder[String]` makes it possible to call `toDS()` on an instance of `RDD[String]`, but the absence of a predefined `Encoder[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Table]` makes it impossible to call `toDS()` on an instance of `RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Table]`.

By the way, `SparkSession.implicits` contains the implicit class `StringToColumn` which has a `$` method. This is how the `$"foo"` expression gets converted to a `Column` instance for column `foo`.

Resolving all the implicit arguments and implicit transformations is why compiling Scala code is so dang slow.